# Should I hash an integer key for unordered containers?

Tags: c++, hash, unordered-map, unordered-set

Looking for guidance on whether I should just use an integer key as the hash value itself, or convert it into a different value, I came across the following advice on this SO question:

- **[What integer hash function are good that accepts an integer hash key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/664014/what-integer-hash-function-are-good-that-accepts-an-integer-hash-key)**

Advice from the answers suggest using a multiplier to convert the integral input value

> In general, you should pick a multiplier that is in the order of your hash size and has no common factors with it. This way the hash function covers all your hash space uniformly.

and

> I found the following algorithm provides a very good statistical distribution. Each input bit affects each output bit with about 50% probability.

However, I then came across another SO question

- **[What is the default hash function used in C++ std::unordered_map?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19411742/what-is-the-default-hash-function-used-in-c-stdunordered-map)**

The answer refers to the GCC implementation, stating the default `std::hash` for integers just returns the bit pattern

> As for the implementation in GCC, the specialization for builtin-types just returns the bit pattern. Here's how they are defined in `bits/functional_hash.h`:
>
> ```
> size_t
> operator()(_Tp __val) const noexcept
> { return static_cast<size_t>(__val); }
> ```

I checked my version (`gcc-5.4.1`) and can confirm this is the case.

So my question is:

For an integral key of type `std::int64_t`, should I be using the implementation provided by the standard library, or should I be using an alternative, such as the function suggested by [Thomas Mueller](https://stackoverflow.com/users/382763/thomas-mueller) in the 1st link above?

```
uint64_t hash(uint64_t x) {
    x = (x ^ (x >> 30)) * UINT64_C(0xbf58476d1ce4e5b9);
    x = (x ^ (x >> 27)) * UINT64_C(0x94d049bb133111eb);
    x = x ^ (x >> 31);
    return x;
}
```

Comment: Try both, measure, and pick the one that performs the best.

Comment: check out an answer of mine here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44668672/hash-function-to-size-of-buckets-for-unordered-containers. If I'm not mistaken, gcc's unordered_map uses a prime table size, so a not-too-good hash function could be adequate. Even the identity relation could be fine.

Comment: But of course, you should not rely on this information too much. A different version/compiler could use a different method (that's why I created my own hashtable implementation: I can rely on it)

Comment: @geza absolutely, thanks, but it is still interesting to understand the mechanics of how the hash function plays with the bucket size

Comment: One thing you should take into consideration is whether your `unordered_map` needs to withstand hash collision flood attacks